# recursive sql query for breadcrumbs

Tags: php, mysql

I need a quick recursive sql query for this database:

```
SITE            CATEGORY        DIR          PARENT_CATEGORY
domain1.com     home            home         
domain1.com     kitchen         kitchen      home
domain1.com     appliances      apps         home
domain1.com     tables          tables       kitchen

domain2.com     home            home-dir     
domain2.com     bathroom        bath         
domain2.com     garden          garden       

domain3.com     fun             funny
```

What I need is a function that will give me an array of parent categories from current to top category. For instance for domain1.com tables it should return:

```
$breadcrumb = Array(
[0]=>Array(
   'title'='home',
   'dir'='home'
);
[1]=>Array(
   'title'='kitchen',
   'dir'='kitchen'
);
[2]=>Array(
   'title'='tables',
   'dir'='tables'
);

);
```

So basically, it should return breadcrumb for requested category & site.
Function ($category,$site) { ...

return array.
}

Comment: and you want then in hierarchical order? You need to have max depth defined

Comment: Yes, I need a function that finds all that have parent defined... when parent='', that is where it is on the top category...

Answer (score 0):

The query works, will give you hierarchy depth upto 7 levels and all parents in a single row.
Some something like:

```
SITE            CATEGORY        level1       level2     level3   level4   level5 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
domain1.com     tables          tables       kitchen    home     NULL     NULL
```

```
select level1, level2, site, category, dir, parent_category
        if(level7 is not null,7,
            if(level6 is not null and level7 is null,6,
                if(level5 is not null and level6 is null,5,
                    if(level4 is not null and level5 is null,4,
                        if(level3 is not null and level4 is null,3,
                            if(level2 is not null and level3 is null,2,1)))))) depth 
  from
      (select  
          site,category,dir,parent_category
          site level1, 
          parent_category level2, 
          (select parent_category from <table> i where one.parent_category=i.category) level3, 
          (select parent_category from <table> i where level3=i.category) level4, 
          (select parent_category from <table> i where level4=i.category) level5, 
          (select parent_category from <table> i where level5=i.category) level6, 
          (select parent_category from <table> i where level6=i.category) level7  
      from  
          <table> one
          WHERE one.site = ?              
      )a;
```

NB: you might need to do some tweaks

Comment: not really. the table stucture that you used is different than the one i posted, and I am sure there can be a query that simply queries the table to get all levels, no matter how many.